# The prime ideals of the ring $K[x]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I was wondering what the prime ideals of the ring $K[x]$ are, where $K$ is a ring. My guess is that it's any ideal generated by a set of irreducible polynomials over the ring $K$. Have I covered all prime Ideals in $K[x]$ or are there any specific prime ideals I may have missed

Comment: Not all the prime ideals are covered. What about the extensions of the prime ideals of $K$ in $K[x]$? These are also prime ideals. There may be more.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg are you saying that the prime ideals must have atleast one irreducible polynomial, or that it must have exactly one irreducible polynomial, and no other generators?

Comment: @Andrew: sorry, I misread your question and I deleted my comment. Also: think about Krish's very judicious comment.

Comment: If $K$ is a noetherian integral domain, then you are right: every prime ideal is generated by a finite set of irreducible polynomials.

Comment: If $K$ is a pid you still have a nice answer. The prime ideals are $(0)$, $(f)$ for an irreducible polynomial and the maximal ones $m=(p,f)$ where $p \in K$ is a prime and $f \in K[x]$ is a polynomial whose reduction in $K/p[x]$ is irreducible.